# What causes icons in the Taskbar to become duplicated like this?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, krita

I have Krita installed on Windows 10. I have its icon pinned in the Taskbar.

In my "Start-up" dir, I have a shortcut to Krita.exe with the flag  `--load-session "stuff"`, in order for Krita to start up when my computer starts for the day, opening my "session".

It works, but the problem is that Krita opens itself in a separate Taskbar icon to the far right, with the pinned Krita Taskbar icon just sitting there.

This is not the first time that something similar to this happened. I don't understand it and I hate it.

What causes "duplicate" Taskbar icons like this? I thought the whole point of this "new" Taskbar was to group icons and avoid clutter.

What to do to prevent this from happening, so that the same program only has one "Taskbar icon/group", which seems to be how it's intended to work?

Comment: Maybe what’s running isn’t really `krita.exe`?

Comment: @DanielB What do you mean by that?

Comment: Close (not exit from) Krita.  It should now exit from the left side Taskbar. Outlook does the very same thing.  If you want Krita open, then either (a) live with both icons; (b) hide the system tray icon; (c) ask Krita support if there is a setting you can use.

Comment: @John I didn't understand any part of your comment. Close Krita? What? Did you read my question at all? And what system tray icon? It doesn't use the system tray at all.

Comment: What I meant is that you started Krita and so it is active in the Taskbar - normal. It also has a system tray icon - normal. So it you are not using Krita at some point, close it so then it should go away from the task bar.

Comment: @John I genuinely cannot tell if you are being serious. Why exactly would closing Krita solve my problem? It would... close Krita. What?

Comment: If I start Outlook, it is in the Task bar. It is also in the System Tray - 2 places. That is what you have in Krita (you said) .  If I close Outlook or Minimize Outlook, it leaves the Task Bar and stays in the System Tray. This is the best analogy I can come up with for you.

Comment: OP is not talking about the system tray. It’s just that some applications don’t stay with their pinned taskbar entries.

Answer (score 0):

There's a setting (Settings > Personalization > Taskbar) that can prevent combining
of app icons on the taskbar. Perhaps yours is set that way.

Comment: I'm not trying to prevent it. I'm trying to *cause* it. To make it clear: I have no such setting set. Other icons are grouped, such as cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce the issue, with a new regular shortcut on the desktop. However, if I copy the shortcut the installer creates in the start menu and modify that, the issue does not occur.

The original shortcut contains some additional metadata that persists when changing it. Without this additional data, Explorer simply treats it as a different application.

---

This solution will not always work. I have some software (wsltty) that always results in a new taskbar entry.